# Mongo DB group records and return selected fields

Tags: mongodb

I want to group the documents on the basis of a specific value. Also I need the selected keys in return.

Here is my document:

```
{
    title: "Add 1",
    userId: 1,
    description: "this is add 1",
    location: {
        city: "Newyork",
        address: "Street 1, Flat # 40"
        },
    createdAt: "2015-10-20",

    title: "Add 2",
    userId: 1,
    description: "this is add 2",
    location: {
        city: "Paris",
        address: "Street 2, Flat # 80"
        },
    createdAt: "2015-10-22",

    title: "Add 3",
    userId: 1,
    description: "this is add 3",
    location: {
        city: "Newyork",
        address: "Street 5, Flat # 58"
        },
    createdAt: "2015-10-23"
}
```

I want to group the documents by `location.city`. Also I need only title and location in return.

What should be the query for above scenario?

I have tried this query:

```
Adds.aggregate([
                  { $match: { userId: params.userId } },
                  { $group: { _id: "$location.city" } },              
              ]);
```

The above query only returns location.city, I want complete object of location & title.

Comment: You could do it using .aggregate if this data was broken down in an array. Not as a single document.

Comment: @Tiramisu I have already tried using aggregate, but the response result is not fine. I grouped the records using location.city, so it just return location.city. Please check the updated question

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your data actually looks like this:

```
[
  {
    title: "Add 1",
    description: "this is add 1",
    location: {
        city: "Newyork",
        address: "Street 1, Flat # 40"
        },
    createdAt: "2015-10-20",
  },
  {
    title: "Add 2",
    description: "this is add 2",
    location: {
        city: "Paris",
        address: "Street 2, Flat # 80"
        },
    createdAt: "2015-10-22",
  },
  {
    title: "Add 3",
    description: "this is add 3",
    location: {
        city: "Newyork",
        address: "Street 5, Flat # 58"
        },
    createdAt: "2015-10-23"
  }
]
```

You could use an aggregate query such as:

```
db.adds.aggregate([
    { $group : 
        { 
            _id : "$location.city", 
            data : { $push : { "title" : "$title", "location" : "$location" } }
        }
    }
]);
```

Comment: The query you sent me will return 2 records, now there are two records with city newyork, which will be grouped as one record. so which record it will bring when grouped, the one with "address": "Street 5, Flat # 58" or the one with "address": "Street 1, Flat # 40" ???

Comment: if you indicate what the result should look like then we can adjust the query accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

userId is missing in your documents, if your collection looks like this your aggregate function is correct.

```
{
    "title": "Add 1",
    "userId": 1,
    "description": "this is add 1",
    "location": {
        "city": "Newyork",
        "address": "Street 1, Flat # 40"
        },
    "createdAt": "2015-10-20"
},
{
    "title": "Add 2",
    "userId": 2 
    "description": "this is add 2",
    "location": {
        "city": "Paris",
        "address": "Street 2, Flat # 80"
        },
    "createdAt": "2015-10-22"
},
{
    "title": "Add 3",
    "userId": 1,
    "description": "this is add 3",
    "location": {
        "city": "Newyork",
        "address": "Street 5, Flat # 58"
        },
    "createdAt": "2015-10-23"
}
```

Test using Mongodb's console

```
db.Adds.aggregate([ 
           { $match: { userId: 1 } }, 
           { $group: { _id: "$location.city" } } 
]);
```

Adding title to your results

```
db.Adds.aggregate([
    { $match: { userId: 1 } }, 
    {
        $group: {  
            _id: "$location.city", 
            title: {$push: "$title"}
        }
    }
]);
```

Comment: Yes my mistake I skipped the userId in the document. I have a question.. The query you sent me will return 2 records, now there are two records with city newyork, which will be grouped as one record. so which record it will bring when grouped, the one with  "address": "Street 5, Flat # 58" or the one with "address": "Street 1, Flat # 40" ???

Comment: If you want to identify each record, aggregate function will not work. So group returned a new document like this, you cannot say what is this user.
{ "_id" : "Newyork", "title" : [ "Add 1", "Add 3" ] }